# Crystal Report Error in Formula Record selection?

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I am getting sum of final values in row and I used formula

```
 q_detail.finalvalue + q_detail.finalvalue
```

But this returns error too.

**I have deleted that formala field**, and it even returns an error as shown below in the image:

[image: Error Image Even when formulae is deleted]

**Question:**

1 - How to get rid of that error, even though I have deleted the formula from formula field?

2 - How to enter serial number in crystal report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not a correct `Record Selection Formula`.

Record selection formula should contain what to be retrived from database. What ever you enter will be used as a where clause in the created query.

Calculations can't be given in record selection formula.

Remove those calculations and write in a formula field and place it in design.

Comment: if i no want to show formula feild as  i have deleted the feild but still error

Comment: Close and reopen the report and check